# FDCAN Loopback mode in stmcubeide

Tags: c, stm32, loopback, can-bus, nucleo

So I was implementing FDCAN  External loopbak mode in STM32H7A3ZIT6Q NUCLEO. Clock configuration: HSI is 64MHz and fdcan frq is 50Mhz and I have done the parameter calculations accordingly.The code is debugging without errors but in the result the RX and TX values are not increasing. What could be the possible error? I referred to controllers tech for the code https://controllerstech.com/stm32-fdcan-in-loopback-mode/

I tried incrementing the index( variable)value and stored them in one byte each ( so 12 values as I have selected 12bytes Fifo for both Rx and Tx).But in the result each byte has value stored as 0 and it is not increasing.